# Unable to set HTML input value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the session value and then set into the HTML input control, but I get error `Unable to get property of undefined or null reference`. Below is my code.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function direct() {
            setInputValue();
        }

        function setInputValue() {
            document.getElementById('secureHash').value = '<%=Session["secureHash"]%>';

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="direct()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="https://www.aaaaxyz.com">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="secureHash" value="" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="mid" value="0000000038" /><br />        
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Why is that? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type is wrong

C#：Session["secureHash"]

VB：Session("secureHash")

And you should add property of **ID** in your input textbox.

So, you should change your code in this way：

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function direct() {
            setInputValue();
        }

        function setInputValue() {
            document.getElementById('secureHash').value = '<%=Session("secureHash")%>';
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="direct()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="https://www.aaaaxyz.com">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="secureHash" name="secureHash" value="" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="mid" value="0000000038" /><br />        
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Try it again!

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the `JS` code that calls `secureHash` is before declaring `secureHash` in `HTML`.

```
document.getElementById('secureHash').value = '<%=Session["secureHash"]%>';
```

what is happening is that you call something in `JS` that is not loaded to your document yet.

I always recommend that you put your `JS` code in the end of your document before the end of body tag.also you can't call the function `direct` while loading the page. you must call it in the end.
one more thing in your code is that secureHash is a `name` and not `id`.
here are the changes you need:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="https://www.aaaaxyz.com">
<div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="secureHash" value="" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="mid" value="0000000038" /><br />        
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
<div>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function direct() {
        setInputValue();
    }

    function setInputValue() {
        document.getElementById('secureHash').value = '<%=Session["secureHash"]%>';

    }
direct();
</script>
</body>
```